# bullet proof way to find pages in Refinery Cms

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, refinerycms

i can find a page I'm looking for just fine, like this:

```
  @my_page = ::Refinery::Page.find('foo')
```

so then i can say <% link_to @my_page.url %>

i then try and protect against the case where that page is deleted, like so:

```
  if ::Refinery::Page.find('foo').present?
    @my_page = ::Refinery::Page.find('foo')
  else
    @my_page = nil
  end
```

i've actually tries several ways of doing this, with exists?, with nil?, etc.  the above is the most basic.

So I then go and delete my page and I get a record not found error.

```
Couldn't find Refinery::Page with id=foo
```

Shouldn't the present? method protect against that error?  How should I be doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do

```
@my_page = ::Refinery::Page.find('foo')
```

it tries to find page by slug first and if it doesn't find it then it tries to find it by id.
If you don't deal with localization you can do

```
@my_page = ::Refinery::Page.find_by_slug('foo')
```

which will return page if it finds it or nil if it doesn't.

With localization it get's complicated but this should do the trick

```
if ::Refinery::Page::Translation.find_by_slug('foo').present?
  @my_page = ::Refinery::Page::Translation.find_by_slug('foo').refinery_page
end
```

Answer (score 1):

How about following the principles of [EAFP](http://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-eafp)?

```
begin
  @my_page = Refinery::Page.find('foo')
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
  @my_page = nil
end
```